# Programmatically selecting option(s) on AJAX sourced Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

Im using the Select2 jQuery plugin (*v4.0.3*) for a project im working on. The select2 instance is ajax sourced, and I was wondering i there is a way to programmatically select options.

I was previously able to set the value via:

```js
$('#input-field').val(['123','456']).trigger('change')
```

When it was **not** ajax sourced. And now I need to get this working with an ajax sourced Select2 instance.

I created a **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLinux/n9myjrfn/)** instance, just so you can see what I mean. Clicking Set Values should select 2 values in the select2 instance.

Thanks!

**P.S.** I even tried setting the `tags` option to `true`, so any value can get selected (even if its not a result from the AJAX query), and it still doesnt work

Comment: looks like your ajax call doesn't get the correct values, however when clearing the select2 box and clicking on the "set values" link everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you can't programmatically select something that hasn't been previously searched and selected from the dropdown.

Select2, when using AJAX data, appears to work by adding previously unknown options to the underlying `select` element when they're discovered. `.val()` is trying to add the items you want, but only the ones that already exist can be added and the rest are ignored. Select2 then gets the `change` event and adjusts the render accordingly.

This should at least send you in a useful direction:

```
$('#set-selected').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var $select = $('.js-data-example-ajax');
  var targets = ["28200583","3620194"];
  targets.forEach(function(v,i,a){
    if(!$('option[value='+v+']',$select).length) {
      $select.append('<option value="'+v+'">'+v+'</option>');
    }
  });
  $select.val(targets).trigger('change');
});
```

Usually the situation with these UI libraries is that you manipulate the control the same way you initialize it, via calls to `.select2()` in this case. However I'm unable to find a command in that form that does what you need in this scenario.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion last night when working on this again. I found a GIT issue on it. I figured it was something along those lines, was just hoping that the Select2 plugin would be cool enough to make AJAX requests for the values passed to the `$.val()` call, but this works just as well. Thanks!